# The ordering does matter in this case, is it because the question specified the order?

Tags: probability

> A box has 30 strips of paper in it. Each strip has a number written on it in a color. There are 3 colors
>   (red, blue, yellow) and the numbers 0 through 9. That is, there are the numbers 0 through 9 in red, in
>   yellow, and in blue. Each strip is folded in half, so that the color and number combination cannot be
>   seen.
>
> Strips are drawn from the box with replacement. What is the chance that the first
>   strip is blue and the second strip is either a green or a 7?

Originally for this question I got $\binom {2}{1} \frac{10}{30} *(\frac{10}{30} +\frac{3}{30}-\frac{1}{30})$

The solution shows that the $\binom {2}{1}$ is redundant.

Is it because the question specified the order in the question "**First** strip is blue, **second** strip is .." If the question were simply asking two draws were made what are the chance that one strip is blue and the other is either green or 7, then we don't take ordering into consideration?

Comment: On the contrary, the ordering DOES matter !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because of the "first" and "second", the order is fixed. Because the draws are done with replacement, each draw can be considered independently and there is no need for $\binom21$.

Comment: Ok perfect, I will try to read the questions more carefully next time.